# why does a function return whole code as a string

Tags: javascript, function, google-apps-script

Working on a web app - on a registration page -
want to make sure that the same id for two different registrations is never a case! - 4 - 5 people are going to use the app!

code :

```
function nextId(lastId){

  var next = parseInt(lastId.split('-')[1]) + 1;

  return ("MORCP-"+ (next).toString());

}

function serverNextRegId(){

  /** --------------------------------------
   * Registration sheet
   * idCol : returns the dynamic column value of Id from headColumns in the sheet
   * lastRow : row value as in sheet 
  ----------------------------*/
  var registration = MS.magicSheet("market","Registration");
  
  var idCol = MS.msCol(registration,"Id");
  
  var lastRow = MS.msLastRow(registration);
  
  /**--------------------------
   * connection sheet
   * working id col
   * lastRow from
   --------------------------*/
  var connection = MS.magicSheet("logs","Connection");
  
  var workingIdCol = MS.msCol(connection,"Working Reg");
  
  var lastRowConn = MS.msLastRow(connection,workingIdCol);

  
  /** ---------------------
   * get data from both sheets  
   --------------------------*/
  var lastId = registration.getRange(lastRow,idCol).getValue();
  var workingIds = connection.getRange(1,workingIdCol,lastRowConn).getValues().flat();
  
  /** ----------------------------------
   * check new id, if it's already in use
   * if in use () nextId
   --------------------------------- */
  var catchNewId = nextId(lastId);
  var check = workingIds.indexOf(catchNewId);
  
  while(check>0){
    catchNewId = nextId(catchNewId);
    check = workingIds.indexOf(catchNewId);
  }

  var newRow = lastRowConn+1;
  /**----------------------------------
   * print the working value to the connection 
   --------------------------------------*/
  connection.getRange(newRow,workingIdCol).setValue(nextId);

}
```

but at last the value prints is the whole function nextId() as string

Could someone explain it for me ?

and let me add : at first I tried

```
var next = (lastId)=>("MORCP-"+ (parseInt(lastId.split('-')[1]) + 1).toString());
```

within the function serverNextRegId()

Is it fine to use it here ?

Comment: `.setValue(nextId)` -> `.setValue(nextId())`

Comment: _"Could someone explain it for me ?"_ - `.setValue()` seems to call `.toString()` on its argument. `.toString()` called on a function will return the source code of that (user defined) function.

Comment: got it ! thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer

Change `.setValue(nextId)` to `.setValue(nextId())`

### Explanation

`.setValue()` seems to call `.toString()` on its argument. `.toString()` called on a function will return the source code of that (user defined) function